# Django 1.8 programming error: relation auth_user doesn't exist when running test

Tags: python, django

I've read already the existing answer about this problem in Stackoverflow. But none worked for me. When I run `manage.py test`, I get the following, although my website run fine!

```
$ ./manage.py test --verbosity=3
manage.py test --verbosity=3
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=project.iobserve.forms,project.iobserve.models,project.iobserve.views --verbosity=3
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
nose.plugins.cover: INFO: Coverage report will include only packages: ['project.iobserve.forms', 'project.iobserve.models', 'project.iobserve.views']
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_iobserve')...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_iobserve" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_iobserve', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: mptt, djangobower, iobserve, staticfiles, twitter, messages, leaflet, allauth, facebook, multiselectfield, django_nose, rest_framework, honeypot
  Apply all migrations: account, sessions, admin, sites, auth, contenttypes, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
Running pre-migrate handlers for application admin
Running pre-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sites
Running pre-migrate handlers for application auth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sessions
Running pre-migrate handlers for application rest_framework
Running pre-migrate handlers for application mptt
Running pre-migrate handlers for application djangobower
Running pre-migrate handlers for application honeypot
Running pre-migrate handlers for application leaflet
Running pre-migrate handlers for application allauth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application account
Running pre-migrate handlers for application socialaccount
Running pre-migrate handlers for application twitter
Running pre-migrate handlers for application facebook
Running pre-migrate handlers for application iobserve
  Creating tables...
    Creating table iobserve_person
    Creating table iobserve_bibliographicreference
    Creating table user_profile
    Creating table iobserve_coordinates
    Creating table iobserve_observingsite
    Creating table iobserve_astronomicalorganisation
    Creating table iobserve_building
    Creating table iobserve_dome
    Creating table iobserve_tool
    Creating table iobserve_observingtool
    Creating table iobserve_telescope
    Creating table iobserve_toolcomponent
    Creating table iobserve_mirror
    Creating table iobserve_astronomicalcoordinates
    Creating table iobserve_alias
    Creating table iobserve_objecttype
    Creating table iobserve_astronomicalflux
    Creating table iobserve_astronomicalobject
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 350, in run_tests
    result = self.run_suite(nose_argv)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 297, in run_suite
    addplugins=plugins_to_add)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 121, in __init__
    **extra_args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 207, in runTests
    result = self.testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 50, in run
    wrapper = self.config.plugins.prepareTest(test)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
    return self.call(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
    result = meth(*arg, **kw)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/plugin.py", line 76, in prepareTest
    self.old_names = self.runner.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 533, in setup_databases
    return super(NoseTestSuiteRunner, self).setup_databases()
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=not keepdb,
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/onekiloparsec/.virtualenvs/iobs-debug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

The only problematic line is the relationship between the UserProfile and the user in my models. Below the UserProfile model. I also ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` individually, sequentially, etc etc. But when I run tests, it fails. I really have no clue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

import hashlib

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
        app_label = 'iobserve'

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}'s profile".format(self.user.username)

    def account_verified(self):
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            result = EmailAddress.objects.filter(email=self.user.email)
            if len(result):
                return result[0].verified
        return False

    def profile_image_url(self):
        fb_uid = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user_id=self.user.id, provider='facebook')
        if len(fb_uid):
            return "http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?width=40&height=40".format(fb_uid[0].uid)
        return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?s=40".format(hashlib.md5(self.user.email).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Can you show the output with `--verbosity=3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `iobserve` app doesn't have any migrations, and you can't have a relation, such as a `OneToOneField`, from an unmigrated app to a migrated app.

You need to run `manage.py makemigrations iobserve` to create the initial migrations for the `iobserve` app. Only when the initial migrations exist, will `manage.py makemigrations` without any app labels create new migrations for that app.

Comment: Thanks so much. I run 'makemigrations' in the past, but in the flow of tests I've made, I may have forgotten it